# update properties of style component using switch statement

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components

I know there's a similar question but what I need is different.

I have declared the common styles that my button will be using and I'm using a function with a switch statement that has different properies for different buttons that I will be using in other pages and for one case I need the border-radius and padding different from the common one, how can I update(or replace) the value without using !important or && {.

Here's the code

```
import { TTheme } from 'src/styles/Themes/Theme';
import styled, { css, FlattenSimpleInterpolation } from 'styled-components';

const getVariantCSS = <T extends TTheme>(props: T): FlattenSimpleInterpolation => {
    const { theme } = props;

    switch (props.variant) {

        case 'secondary':
            return css`
                background-color: ${theme.colors.white};
                color: ${theme.colors.primary};
                border: ${theme.borders.solid1} ${theme.colors.primary};
                &:hover {
                    color: ${theme.colors.white};
                    background-color: ${theme.colors.shades.hoverLight};
                    border: ${theme.borders.none};
                    box-shadow: ${theme.boxShadows.primary};
                }
            `;

        case 'half':
            return css`
                color: ${theme.colors.white};
                background-color: ${theme.colors.primary};
                && {
                    border-radius: ${theme.radius.half};
                    padding: ${theme.paddings.small};
                }
                border: ${theme.borders.solid2} ${theme.colors.white};
            `;

        case 'dark':
            return css`
                background-color: ${theme.colors.tertiary};
                color: ${theme.colors.primary};
                border: ${theme.borders.solid1} ${theme.colors.primary};
                &:hover {
                    color: ${theme.colors.white};
                    background-color: ${theme.colors.shades.hoverDark};
                    box-shadow: ${theme.boxShadows.primary};
                    filter: ${theme.filter.brightness};
                    border: ${theme.borders.none};
                    opacity: ${theme.opacity.default};
                }
            `;

        default:
            return css`
                background-color: ${theme.colors.primary};
                color: ${theme.colors.white};
                border: ${theme.borders.none};
                box-shadow: ${theme.boxShadows.primary};
                &:hover {
                    color: ${theme.colors.white};
                    background-color: ${theme.colors.shades.hoverLight};
                }
            `;
    }
};

export const StyledButton = styled.button`
    ${getVariantCSS}
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: ${(props) => props.theme.paddings.medium};
    display: ${(props) => props.theme.content.display.flex};
    flex-direction: ${(props) => props.theme.content.flexDirection.row};
    justify-content: ${(props) => props.theme.content.justifyContent.center};
    align-items: ${(props) => props.theme.content.alignItems.center};
    flex-grow: ${(props) => props.theme.content.flexGrow.one};
    border-radius: ${(props) => props.theme.radius.button};
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the cascade. just place "getVariantsCSS" below the main styles and then the desired styles will be applied and then "important" and "&&" is not needed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#the_cascade

```
export const StyledButton = styled.button`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: ${(props) => props.theme.paddings.medium};
    display: ${(props) => props.theme.content.display.flex};
    flex-direction: ${(props) => props.theme.content.flexDirection.row};
    justify-content: ${(props) => props.theme.content.justifyContent.center};
    align-items: ${(props) => props.theme.content.alignItems.center};
    flex-grow: ${(props) => props.theme.content.flexGrow.one};
    border-radius: ${(props) => props.theme.radius.button};
    ${getVariantCSS}
`
```